# What is the fastest test to determine if my webhoster supports ruby/rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am searching for a very quick and easy way to determine if my webhoster supports ruby / ruby on rails.
Is there an easy way like phpinfo() or something?

```
<?php
   phpinfo();
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can run phpinfo on your server, you could check for "mod_passenger" in the list of installed Apache modules.

However, if your webhost doesn't clearly advertise its support for ruby/rails, stay away from it, it'll only give you headaches.  There are cheap/free options to test your rails skills, such as Heroku.com.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby is not like PHP. You can't just point your browser to a Ruby file to execute it. The best test is to SSH into the server (if possible) and try executing the `ruby` binary. Also, doesn't it appear on the host's feature list?

Comment: No, I can not ssh into the server. And ruby is not on the feature list. I thought I try it, but it seems it is not as easy to try as is php.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you can't ssh into your shared server? Otherwise, why don't you simply upload a ruby file and see if it works?

Comment: Hmm. I created a simple HelloWorld.rb. On accessing it I see the code, not the result. Seems my hoster does not provide ruby.. thanks.

Comment: This is the wrong conclusion to draw from that result.  This does NOT mean your host does not support ruby on rails.

Comment: see the answer by dtrasbo, this answer is **WRONG**